# How to exclude & include files for build in Eclipse based on some flag

Tags: c++, eclipse, build

I have a #define xyz, i want to exclude files if the #define is unset and include files if it is set.
Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Or If i would like to put it in other way, How best can i exclude files for build in Eclipse based on like say some flags or something.

Comment: Such that if i check out the code i don need to re-exclude the files again. Is there some settings which could be set via a script or something?

Comment: Maybe lookup `#ifdef`.

Comment: Also, please edit your original question with the new info rather than adding comments.